# Complex functions and real function

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, derivatives, partial-derivative, analytic-functions

This is a brief part of an exercise related to differential geometry on the minimal surface Scherk. However I am stuck in an analytical part.

Let $$F(x,y)= \arg\left(\frac{z+i}{z-i}\right)$$ where $z = x + iy$ with $z$ different from $\pm i$, and $\arg$ is the argument of the point with the real axis.

Let
$$\phi(z) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$$

Show that $\phi$ is analytic.

Any hints on substitutions or steps to find out what are $\partial_{x}F$ and $\partial_{y}F$? ?

Comment: Chain rule is a good start, or the fact that $arg(a/b) = arg(a)-arg(b)$

Comment: $F$ is *harmonic* (it is locally the imaginary part of a logarithm), and that implies that $\phi(z) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$ is holomorphic.

Answer (score 2):

Let $D$ be any disk not containing the points $i$ or $-i$. The function $(z+i)/(z-i)$ is holomorphic and non-zero in $D$, and therefore has a complex logarithm in $D$. Let $U$ and $V$ be the real and imaginary part of that holomorphic logarithm:
$$
 f(z) = \log \frac{z+i}{z-i} =U(z) + i V(z) \, .
$$
Differentiation and using the Cauchy-Riemann equations gives
$$
 f'(z) = \frac{1}{z+i} - \frac{1}{z-i} = U_x(z) + i V_x(z) = V_y(z) + i V_x(z) \, .
$$
$F$ is (apart from a possible constant multiple of $2\pi$) the imaginary part of $f$, so that
$$
    \phi(z) = F_x(z) - iF_y(z)= V_x(z) -iV_y(z)\\
 =-if'(z) = \frac{-2}{z^2+1}\, .
$$

Comment: Very diligent manipulation!!